# Spring Override MessageTag Class

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am developing a web application where it was needed to output text both in some custom locale and RequestContext.getLocale().
For this i wanted to modify `<spring:message>` tag, so that it accepts "languageCode" parameter (and when "languageCode" param is not provided, RequestContext.getLocale() is used).

Best way seems to extend `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag` class and create my own tag library.

But is it possible to do so, as all data-members of `MessageTag` class are private with no getters?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/MessageTag.java

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why so complex, if you want to force a locale use a `FixedLocaleResolver` instead. Why on earth would you want to override the message tag, you would also have to create your own tag library for that. Have you actually checked how Springs I18N support works?